# Auto-generate the code-behind name of designer collection items

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have a custom control with a public collection marked as `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content`.

When I add items to the collection using the designer, it adds them to the designer file and assigns all desired values but it gives each element of the collection a generic name, such as `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, etc.  I want the "Name" property of each item to become the code name of the item so that I can then access the item by its name in code.

This is the functionality of how a ContextMenuStrip and ToolStrip works.  In those cases, the Name property shows up as `(Name)` in the property grid.

Is there an attribute or something I can use to gain this functionality?  Or do I have to write a whole custom designer dialog?  If so, **what's an example of the simplest way I could go about achieving this?**

Comment: Well I don't know enough on the subject to venture a full answer but I was intrigued by the question so I did some research. It looks like there is a `ToolStripDesinger` class in the System.Windows.Forms.Design assembly. And there's no attributes on the `Name` Properties. I used dotPeak [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2011/05/11/dotpeak.aspx) o_O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try inheriting from Component to get that feature.

In this example, I created a class called `PanelItem`, which will be the class used in my collection by my own Panel class.  I added `DesignTimeVisible(false)` so that it doesn't populate the component tray in the designer.

Also, I added a `Name` property that is hidden from the designer but can be used in code.  It seemed to work in my tests:

```
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public class PanelItem : Component  {

  [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "")]
  public string PanelText { get; set; }

  private string name = string.Empty;

  [Browsable(false)]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public string Name {
    get {
      if (base.Site != null) {
        name = base.Site.Name;
      }
      return name;
    }
    set {
      name = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Then my custom panel control:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel {
  private List<PanelItem> panelItems = new List<PanelItem>();

  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public List<PanelItem> PanelItems {
    get { return panelItems; }
  }
}
```

Resulted in:

[image]

Comment: That seems to do the job.  This isn't a big deal, but do you know how to have it mirror the (Name) with the Name string property of the class the way other components do?

Comment: @Moozhe Not sure I follow.  If I look at a ContextMenuStrip and open up the "Items Collection Editor" and add a menu, the name becomes "toolStripMenuItem1".  Same thing happens here: by default I get "panelItem1", "panelItem2", etc. and it appears in the Design category under "(Name)".  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: With a component, for example a Control, when you set the **(Name)** field in the designer it also sets the **Name** public property.  This property is set to Browsable(false) so you don't see it in the property grid, but the designer sets it automatically based on whatever you entered in the **(Name)** field.  It's then used as a runtime name/string key.

Comment: @Moozhe OK, I think I understand the issue.  I updated the example with a Name property.

Comment: Brilliant, I knew I should have looked harder using ILSpy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your custom control itself is going to require a DesignerSerializer, and that merely decorating the collection with the the `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` will not be sufficient.

I used ILSpy to check: ToolStrip has its DesignerSerializer set to an internal ToolStripCodeDomSerializer, which I think is responsible for generating all the code properties involved.

I think implementing this will be a bit of specialized work. Here's the MSDN article to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171834.aspx. You're looking for an implementation of the CodeDomSerializer, I believe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer.aspx.